# Name for this type of connector?

Tags: connector, identification, board, socket

Can Anyone help me to identify this board to board connector? 
7 springs connector on top and 8 on the bottom.

[image]

answer
Found a Korean company producing it. Thanks.

This is the plug on the other end...
[image]

Connector with Ruler for size reference..
[image]
[image]

Comment: Might help if you stated where you got it from.

Comment: I took it out from a Mazda modular cd player. It seems like all their plug in audio component uses them.

Comment: Do you have a ruler (0.1mm or 0.010inch) to identify the dimensions, such as spacing between contacts along the bottom row? 

If it's 1mm pitch, maybe Hirose DF9-15 series of SMT plug/socket; ask samples from digikey.com: DF9-15P-1V(32) DF9-15S-1V(32) DF9B-15P-1V(32) DF9B-15S-1V(32).

Looks like 15-pin, dual row; is it 1mm, 2.5mm, or 3mm pitch? Hard to tell without a size reference.

And, any manufacturer logo stamped in the plastic body? (HRS=Hirose, S=Samtec, AMP, 3M, Molex, etc?)

Comment: @MarkU Wow The Hirose actually looks really close. I have added 2 more screenshot with a ruler as reference. 
I have also try to look for any form of marking on the connector, but it is clean.

Comment: Small side note: if this is from a car, it is very likely either a customer-specific SKU which passes their specs instead of something available on the free market.

Comment: @user36129: That's what i am really afraid of, but I have seen 3rd party creating custom module which utilise the connector. So fingers cross. I am hoping this is not a proprietary item.

Comment: @Percy If you found the answer, please consider posting it as an actual answer (rather than editing the question) so this will not appear as an unanswered question.

Comment: Answering your own question is OK, you've done the research. And this would help out the next person who goes looking for this kind of connector. Cheers --   http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Looks to me like a fancy dip socket

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be a Molex board-to-board connector but I'm confused about its actual name. The best way may be to ask Molex tech support.

[image]